# How do I get revenue from product ordered report?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, magento-enterprise

I want to show Revenue from product under Reports> Products> Products Ordered Grid.

I know for the Grid I have to override `app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Report\Product\Sold\Grid.php` but how do I get revenue for the product.

[image: Scrrenshot]

Answer (score 0):

See the answer posted here for the basis of my code suggestion

[Magento: How to display how many times a product has been sold?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14196250/get-total-revenue-generated-by-a-product-in-magento)

since you are wanting to display this value in the frontend, i'm assuming phtml, so I'll code it that way, and just attempt to multiply final price by qty sold.

```
<?php
        // Enter your product ID here 
        $id = 123; 

        // Load the product collection and do some filters   
        $_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
            ->addOrderedQty()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('id', $id)
            ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc')
            ->getFirstItem();

        // Since the filter selects one product, we can use it here as the single result
        $product = $_productCollection;

        // Load the tax helper
        $_taxHelper  = Mage::helper('tax');

        // Get the final price of the product
        $finalprice = $_taxHelper->getPrice($product, $product->getFinalPrice(), true);


        // Print the results
        echo $product->getName() . " total revenue: " . (int)$product->ordered_qty * $finalprice;
?>
```

This is untested, coded on the fly, but the concepts are pretty basic so you should have no trouble adapting what I've shown to do what you need.